# Finding radius r of the overlappable sphere(s) in 3D image

Tags: geometry, 3d, image-processing

My current problem:

- I have an input 3D binary image (a 3D matrix that has only 0 and 1) that consists of random numbers of sphere with radius r.
- We do not know how many spheres are there in the image.
- All spheres have the same radius r, but we do not know radius r.
- Spheres are all over the place in the image and can overlap each other.
- example image is given below.

My requirement:

- **what is the radius r?**

Currently, I simply just flatten the image to get rid of the z axis and perform edge detection and I am trying Hough Transform using: http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/hough-circles.html

However, with Hough Transform, I see that the variables minimum radius, maximum radius, and number of circles have to be specified. I have tried a few attempts below:

[image: known radius]

[image: unknown radius]

Given the correct parameters, Hough Transform can detect the circles just fine. But in the real application, I do not know how many spheres are there, and making the program attempting to guess minimum and maximum radius seems not feasible. Are there other ways to accomplish this?

Cross-link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653291/finding-radius-r-of-the-overlappable-spheres-in-3d-image

Comment: You don't need to know radius of the circles in advance to perform the Hough circle transform; the radius just becomes another dimension of the parameter space. See http://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg782/lectures/lecture_10/lec782_05_10.pdf ...In your volume data, you can do a 3D analogue of edge detection, and the Hough parameter space will be 4-dimensional: three parameters for the position of the center of the sphere, and one parameter for its radius.

Comment: In theory, it suffices to analyze a small arc of a circle, since the curvature uniquely determines the radius. However, you might also imagine that you have all circles that are tangent to a given point. The resulting figure is a circle with double the radius that you seek, so in extreme cases, the problem is unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution and much more computationally efficient when compared to Hough Transform is to use the distance transform:

- Find the surface of your spheres (i.e. the pixels that have value 1 and have at least one neighboring 0 pixel);
- Compute the [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) with respect to the spheres surface, but constrain the computation only to pixels that are internal to the spheres. The output will be a distance map;
- The radius will be exactly the maximum value in your distance map.

Another advantage of this solution when compared to Hough transform is that it provides a much more precise value for the radius.